# Send all request for a TLD to one IP

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq

I've been fighting this issue for a few days and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am developing a sight that is going to use dynamic subdomains so I am trying to get all domains that end with .test to route to one IP address (I realize that not just subdomains will route but all .test domains but I develop all my sights under the .test domain).

I have been trying to set up dnsmasq to accomplish this but I can't seem to get it to work. I know that NetworkManager runs its own instance of dnsmasq. I have made the following entry in multiple places trying to get this to work. The entry I am trying is: *address=/.test/192.168.10.10* .

I have made entries in:

- /etc/NetworkManger/dnsmasq.d/hosts.conf
- /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d/hosts.conf
- /etc/dnsmasq.d/hosts.conf
- /etc/dnsmasq.conf

I was trying it first with installing dnsmasq NetworkManager directories. After that didn't work, I installed dnsmasq and tried the other locations and that didn't work either.

I have tried restarting my network interface and I have restarted my machine both multiple times.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've been on the same boat for a few days as well. Here's what I did to make it work (but I am not sure if it's a proper way how to solve the issue).

Ubuntu, by default, has stub DNS server (listening at port `53`) called `systemd-resolved`. I couldn't make `dnsmasq` work without disabling the stub in a first place. I am not sure if turinig off `systemd-resolved` is a way to go, yet as it's called Stub DNS I guess it should be fine (`sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service`).

Then I made changes to the `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`: uncomment `bind-interfaces` and make dnsmasq listen to `127.0.0.1:53` (`listen=127.0.0.1` and `port=53`).

Tell NetworkManager to use `dnsmasq` as DNS server by adding `dns=dnsmasq` to  `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` (in `[main]` category).

Now, as `systemd-resolved` is turned off, you are free to edit `/etc/resolve.conf` (at least until you install another service that generates and manages `resolve.conf`). `nameserver 127.0.0.53` is no longer needed, change it to `nameserver 127.0.0.1`.

You should now be able to configure `dnsmasq` to resolve your TLD to address you want. Create `/etc/dnsmasq.d/test.conf` file with `address=/.test/127.0.0.1`.

Restart both, `dnsmasq` and `NetworkManager` (`sudo servicectl restart dnsmasq.service`, `sudo servicectl restart network-manager.service`).

```
developer@ubuntu:~$ dig hi_eric.test

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> hi_eric.test
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59442
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hi_eric.test.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
hi_eric.test.       0   IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Jul 01 07:30:46 PDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46
```

Downside is that this forced me to use hardcoded DNS servers for outgoing traffic (because right now `.test` is the only domain your server can resolve). I've had to add `resolv-file=/etc/resolve.dnsmasq` to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and create `/etc/resolve.dnsmasq` with Google public DNS servers:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Restart `dnsmasq` the last time (`sudo servicectl restart dnsmasq.service`). Now everything, more-less, should work fine. `.test` is resolved to `127.0.0.1`, everything else is resolved by Google open DNS servers. You can tweak `dnsmasq` configuration, increase cache size and so on.

Like I've said, I am not 100% sure about this solution (and I am 99% sure there is better solution), but it works. I hope someone else will correct everything I did wrong and guide you with a better and more stable way to solve your (and mine!) issue. Cheers!